# JSON to UITableView Swift 4 recently played songs

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm still very new to coding so please go easy on me. My issue I'm having is I am trying to add my recently played songs to my Radio Station's app. I added a tableviewcontroller and added the cell already. The cell is setup with album artwork(cover), song title(title) and song artist(artist). I'm just stuck at getting the JSON info into my cell. Here is what my JSON data looks like. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I switched this line:

```
guard let urlText = URL (string: "http://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt")
```

To this line:

```
guard let urlText = URL (string: currentStation.longDesc)
```

Here is the error I get: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: How are you deserializing the JSON? Have you parsed this to objects?

Comment: @nayem I have no idea. I’m super new to coding. I know the basic of basics. LoL

Comment: Well, okay. Then you need to have some basic understanding for what you need. Some google searches (as: JSON decoding in Swift 4, UITableView data mapping) will help you in this regard. Or you can have a look at [this](https://www.quickbytes.io/tutorials/introduction-to-json-and-codable-in-swift-4) quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nayem said it is best to read through some tutorials to learn about parsing JSON and how to deal with your response.

Here is an example in which I just copied your JSON Data and made a JSON file within the MainBundle:

```
//---------------------
//MARK: Your CustomCell
//---------------------

class YourCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet var songTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var artistLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var songCover: UIImageView!
}

//----------
//MARK: JSON
//----------

//The Initial Response From The JSON
struct Response: Codable {

var playHistory: Album


}

//The Album Received Which Is An Array Of Song Data
struct Album: Codable {
var song: [SongData]

}

//The SongData From The PlayHistory Album
struct SongData: Codable{

var album: String
var artist: String
var cover: String
var duration: String
var programStartTS: String
var title: String

}

//-----------------
//MARK: UITableView
//-----------------

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource{


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return songs.count
}


   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //1. Create A Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCell

    //2. Set It's Text
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel.text = songs[indexPath.row].artist

    //3. Get The Image
    if let imageURL = URL(string: songs[indexPath.row].cover){

        let request = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (imageData, response, error) in

            if let error = error{

                print(error)

            }else{

                guard let image = imageData else { return }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.songCover.image = UIImage(data: image)
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }

            }
        }


        request.resume()
    }

    return cell

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("""
        **Album \(indexPath.row) Selected**
        Album = \(songs[indexPath.row].album)
        Artist = \(songs[indexPath.row].artist)
        Cover = \(songs[indexPath.row].cover)
        Duration = \(songs[indexPath.row].duration)
        Start = \(songs[indexPath.row].programStartTS)
        Title = \(songs[indexPath.row].title)
        """)
   }

  }

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//1. Create An Array To Store The SongData
var songs = [SongData]()

//2. Create A UITableView As An IBOutlet
@IBOutlet var albumTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()

    albumTableView.delegate = self
    albumTableView.dataSource = self

    //2. Load The JSON From The URL
    guard let urlText = URL(string:"https://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt") else { return }

    do{
        //a. Get The Data From The From The File
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText)

        //b. Decode The Data To Our Structs
        let albumData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

        //c. Append The Songs Array With The PlayHistory
        albumData.playHistory.song.forEach { songs.append($0) }

        //d. Test Some Data
        print("""
            **The First Album Details**
            Album = \(songs[0].album)
            Artist = \(songs[0].artist)
            Cover = \(songs[0].cover)
            Duration = \(songs[0].duration)
            Start = \(songs[0].programStartTS)
            Title = \(songs[0].title)
        """)

        //3. Load The Data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.albumTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }catch{

        print(error)
    }

   }
}
```

**Update:** 
Using The Example Within A UITableViewController:

```
//---------------------
//MARK: Your CustomCell
//---------------------

class YourCell: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet var songTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var artistLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var songCover: UIImageView!

}

//----------
//MARK: JSON
//----------

//The Initial Response From The JSON
struct Response: Codable {

var playHistory: Album

}

//The Album Received Which Is An Array Of Song Data
struct Album: Codable {
var song: [SongData]

}

//The SongData From The PlayHistory Album
struct SongData: Codable{

var album: String
var artist: String
var cover: String
var duration: String
var programStartTS: String
var title: String
}


class ViewController: UITableViewController {

//1. Create An Array To Store The SongData
var songs = [SongData]()

override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    //2. Load The JSON From The Main Bundle

    guard let urlText = URL(string:"https://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt") else { return }


    do{
        //a. Get The Data From The From The File
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: urlText)

        //b. Decode The Data To Our Structs
        let albumData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)

        //c. Append The Songs Array With The PlayHistory
        albumData.playHistory.song.forEach { songs.append($0) }

        //d. Test Some Data
        print("""
            **The First Album Details**
            Album = \(songs[0].album)
            Artist = \(songs[0].artist)
            Cover = \(songs[0].cover)
            Duration = \(songs[0].duration)
            Start = \(songs[0].programStartTS)
            Title = \(songs[0].title)
            """)

        //3. Load The Data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }catch{

        print(error)
    }

}

//-----------------
//MARK: UITableView
//-----------------


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return songs.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //1. Create A Cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCell

    //2. Set It's Text
    cell.songTitle.text = songs[indexPath.row].title
    cell.artistLabel.text = songs[indexPath.row].artist

    //3. Get The Image
    if let imageURL = URL(string: songs[indexPath.row].cover){

        let request = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { (imageData, response, error) in

            if let error = error{

                print(error)

            }else{

                guard let image = imageData else { return }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.songCover.image = UIImage(data: image)
                    cell.setNeedsLayout()
                    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                }

            }
        }


        request.resume()
    }

    return cell

}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("""
        **Album \(indexPath.row) Selected**
        Album = \(songs[indexPath.row].album)
        Artist = \(songs[indexPath.row].artist)
        Cover = \(songs[indexPath.row].cover)
        Duration = \(songs[indexPath.row].duration)
        Start = \(songs[indexPath.row].programStartTS)
        Title = \(songs[indexPath.row].title)
        """)
   }

  }
```

Comment: Why are the members in the struct declared as implicit unwrapped optional? Don't do that. Never do that if the members are initialized in an `init` method (what `Codable` does). The JSON clearly provides all fields so declare the members as non-optional and remove the exclamation marks. If a  member in a struct adopting `Codable` can be `nil` declare it as regular optional (`?`)

Comment: @JoshRobbins Thank you so much sir. I’ve been doing a ton of research but nothing clearly explains my situation. My JSON isn’t local it is: https://streamdb3web.securenetsystems.net/player_status_update/JACKSON1_history.txt Would that make a difference?

Comment: You would just need to change the URL... I have updated the answer above. If your happy with it please mark as the answer...

Comment: @JoshRobbins I keep getting a bunch of errors now; Use of undeclared type 'UIViewController' also Use of undeclared type 'UITableView' also 'super' members cannot be referenced in a root class also Use of unresolved identifier 'Data'. There are a few more.

Comment: Please see the update. The reason it didn't work is because you are using a UITableViewController.

Comment: All fixed thanks @JoshRobbins now question, how do I get the title, artist & image into my cell that I already setup with 2 UILabels and 1 UIImage? I’ve been playing with the code for hours and hours and watching tutorials on YouTube with no luck. My title label is called songTitle, my artist label is called songArtist and my album cover artwork label is called songCover. Please help.

Comment: Updated Answer again. Please mark as the answer now :)

Comment: @JoshRobbins I updated my question above with the code in both of my view controllers I have. TableViewCell.Swift & TableViewController.Swift. I keep getting these errors: https://ibb.co/mrVAXn
https://ibb.co/gMfAXn
https://ibb.co/mcqYk7
https://ibb.co/fayayS

Comment: @JoshRobbins Here is what my TableViewController looks like: https://ibb.co/gWGsCn

Comment: @JoshRobbins I'm so sorry to keep bugging you. I think you almost got it. I am now just getting this error: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1b7245628) to 'MyAppName.TableCell' (0x102071ed0). YourCell in your code is TableCell.

Comment: Change this: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

Comment: @JoshRobbins Thanks for all your help sir. You Rock!!! It works perfectly now. I have a few more things to work out but this was the major issue I was having. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoshRobbins I got 2 more questions, how would I have a placeholder image or insert a default image if no image is pulled from the JSON and also if I wanted to have the JSON link pulled from my local JSON instead of a direct link because the station changes depending on what the listener selects. I have 4 stations that each have it’s own local JSON that has: stationImage, stationStreamUrl, stationShortDescription and stationLongDescription. I inserted the recently played JSON link into the stationLongDescription. How can I pull in the stationLongDescription into the link on this code you did?